# How calculate an average value of the most recent events across groups in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with events (timestamp, value, company id etc).

EXAMPLE:

```
timestamp   value   name    nusers
0   2023-06-01 10:46:11 -1  A   1000
1   2023-06-01 11:12:12 1   A   1000
2   2023-06-01 15:52:44 0   A   1000
3   2023-06-01 18:24:15 0   A   1000
4   2023-06-01 19:19:58 1   A   1000
0   2023-06-01 07:00:41 0   B   2000
1   2023-06-01 09:44:46 -1  B   2000
2   2023-06-01 15:06:21 1   B   2000
3   2023-06-01 15:32:35 0   B   2000
4   2023-06-01 21:55:05 -1  B   2000
0   2023-06-01 08:20:33 0   C   3000
1   2023-06-01 15:02:17 -1  C   3000
2   2023-06-01 17:09:25 1   C   3000
3   2023-06-01 21:51:31 0   C   3000
4   2023-06-01 22:12:48 0   C   3000
```

and for each event I need to calculate an average value of the most recent events across companies at that moment in time. Of course, the most straightforward way would be just loop through all rows, take the most recent events for each company less than the current tie stamp, and calculate an average.

So for the dataframe above the 'naive' code that works looks like that:

```py
res=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    recent=df[df.timestamp<=row.timestamp]
    latest_values=recent.groupby('name').last()
    res.append(dict(timestamp=row.timestamp, value=latest_values.value.mean()))

aggregated_df=pd.DataFrame(res)
aggregated_df.sort_values('timestamp', inplace=True)
aggregated_df
```

which results in what I need:

```
    timestamp   value
5   2023-06-01 07:00:41 0.000000
10  2023-06-01 08:20:33 0.000000
6   2023-06-01 09:44:46 -0.500000
0   2023-06-01 10:46:11 -0.666667
1   2023-06-01 11:12:12 0.000000
11  2023-06-01 15:02:17 -0.333333
7   2023-06-01 15:06:21 0.333333
8   2023-06-01 15:32:35 0.000000
2   2023-06-01 15:52:44 -0.333333
12  2023-06-01 17:09:25 0.333333
3   2023-06-01 18:24:15 0.333333
4   2023-06-01 19:19:58 0.666667
13  2023-06-01 21:51:31 0.333333
9   2023-06-01 21:55:05 0.000000
14  2023-06-01 22:12:48 0.000000
```

But I wonder if there is a more pandas-like way of having the same result.

Comment: How big is your data ? how many different companies (or different values in names) ?

Comment: number of companies is quite low (no more than 20). The data is relatively small now, but it tends to get bigger since we keep collecting the events in real time

Comment: Why not use df.apply? 
`def compute_avg(row):
    recent = df[df['timestamp'] <= row['timestamp']]
    latest_values = recent.groupby('name').last()
    return latest_values['value'].mean()

df['average_value'] = df.apply(compute_avg, axis=1)
aggregated_df = df[['timestamp', 'average_value']].sort_values('timestamp')
print(aggregated_df)`

With more rows of data you can try parallel processing if that is too slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works.

```py
df.sort_values("timestamp").set_index(["timestamp", "name"])\
    ["value"].unstack().ffill().mean(axis=1)

#Out[]: 
#timestamp
#2023-06-01 07:00:41    0.000000
#2023-06-01 08:20:33    0.000000
#2023-06-01 09:44:46   -0.500000
#2023-06-01 10:46:11   -0.666667
#2023-06-01 11:12:12    0.000000
#2023-06-01 15:02:17   -0.333333
#2023-06-01 15:06:21    0.333333
#2023-06-01 15:32:35    0.000000
#2023-06-01 15:52:44   -0.333333
#2023-06-01 17:09:25    0.333333
#2023-06-01 18:24:15    0.333333
#2023-06-01 19:19:58    0.666667
#2023-06-01 21:51:31    0.333333
#2023-06-01 21:55:05    0.000000
#2023-06-01 22:12:48    0.000000
#dtype: float64
```

Components:

1. Sort values so that in chronological order
2. Set index for `timestamp` and `name`
3. Take the `value` column only
4. Then unstack (so names are different columns)
5. Forward fill so last value in time for each name for each timestamp
6. Take the mean for each row (timestamp)